# GetElementByTagName in Node loop

Tags: java, xml, dom

I need to get the value of the "location" element, but I'm having trouble. The chapter we're on is about traverse, NodeIterators, and NodeFilters,Im not sure how to implement that.

The result I need is:

> Jay Cooke State Park Winter Events
>
> Event Name: Lil Park Peeps - Slumbering Bears
>
> Event Name: Winter Encounters - Snowshoe Hike

I'm tried the examples but I'm having trouble with seeing how it works for that XML file.

```
<DEvent>
<event eid="3">Lil' Park PEEPS - Slumbering Bears</event>
<date>2/04/2016</date>
<time>10:30-11:30 AM</time>
<description>
This program series is a preschool envinromental education program designed for ages 2-5 years. Each month explores a different topic through engaging songs, stories, hands on activities and outdoor exploration
</description>
<location>Jay Cooke State Park</location>
<cost>Free</cost>
<infoPhone>218-384-4610, Ext 227</infoPhone>
<infoEmail>kris.hiller@state.mnu.us</infoEmail>
</DEvent>
<DEvent>...</DEvent>
<DEvent>
<event eid="5">Winter Encounters - Snowshoe Hike</event>
<date>2/06/2016</date>
<time>1:00-2:30 PM</time>
<description>
Join us on these snowshoe hikes to discover the park in winter to see what we encounter in the woods or along the river. Child and adult snowshoes are available
</description>
<location>Jay Cooke State Park</location>
<cost>Vehicle Permit to the Park</cost>
<infoPhone>218-384-4610, Ext. 227</infoPhone>
<infoEmail>kris.hiller@state.mn.us</infoEmail>
</DEvent>


    public class stepThrough {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("DNREvents.xml");
        try{
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();  
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
        
        NodeList eventList = doc.getElementsByTagName("DEvent");
        for (int i=0; i< eventList.getLength(); i++) { 
            Node thisNode = eventList.item(i);
            
            Node event = thisNode.getChildNodes().item(0).getNextSibling();
            String location = event.item(5).getNodeValue();
        }
        
        Recursion(doc);
        
        }
        catch(Exception ex){ 
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void Recursion(Node thisNode){
        int type = thisNode.getNodeType();
        String name = thisNode.getNodeName();
        String value = thisNode.getNodeValue();
        
        
            System.out.println("Event name:" + type+ name+value );
        
        
        
        for(Node child =thisNode.getFirstChild();
                child !=null;
                child = child.getNextSibling()){
            Recursion(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dejames/xml-checker. Please take a look.

Comment: Never used gitHub before

Comment: https://github.com/dejames/xml-checker/blob/master/src/ComparisonTest.java. The required java file.